# Javascript OOP Semi-circular inheritance

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance

I try to resolve in a cleaner way that I made the following problem :

I've got two class A and B where A inherit from B.
What I want is when I call a method of the class B via the class A I get a new instance of B and then the method is executed, and keep the inheritance of instance A.

Note that the methods of B must return 'this' for chaining.

**Example :**

```
var classA = new class A();
classA.setName("John");

var result1 = classA.methodOfClassB().otherMethodOfClassB();
var result2 = classA.methodOfClassB().otherMethodOfClassB();
var result3 = result1.otherMethodOfClassB();

console.log(result1 === result2); //false
console.log(result1 === result3); //true

//Call a method of class A from class B
console.log(result1.methodOfClassAGetName()); //John
console.log(result1.methodOfClassAGetName());  //John
```

**My implementation**

```
function classA() {
    var self = this;

    self.methAclassA = function() {
        /* ... */

        console.log(this.methAclassB());
    };

    classB.call(self, true);
    return (self);
}


function classB(isNew) {
    var self = this;

    var _getNewInstance = function() {
        var instance = new classB(false);
        instance.__proto__ = self;

        return (instance);
    };

    self.methAclassB = function() {
        if (isNew) {
            return (_getNewInstance().methAclassB());
        }

        /* ... */

        return (self);
    };
}
```

Thank you in advance !
(Sorry for the English, this is not my first language)

Comment: So what's the problem? What doesn't work? Why do you want to do this in the first place?

Comment: It's working be I'm looking for a cleaner way. I consider that make a condition at the top of each method of classB is not clean.

Comment: Explaining the problem rather than asking for an alternative way of implementing your proposed solution would be a better idea. This whole design looks odd.

Comment: Considering JavaScript is (atm) not OOP language, but a prototypal one I would advise against trying to force it to be OOP, it's a lot of pain of managing a lot of bootstrap code in the long run. Alternatively you could consider TypeScript (or ES6) that would handle a lot of nuisances for you.